# How do you get tab to wrap to the next line in HTML?

Tags: html, css

When setting `white-space:pre-wrap`, the following HTML breaks the line on the tab, with the tab appearing at the end of the first line.

*HTML:*

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap; width:70px">Some text\tsome more text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(where \t is the literal tab character, rather than the escape sequence)

*Output (Chrome):*

```
Some text\t
some 
more text
```

When you adjust the width, either the tab character appears on the first line, or the whole of "text\t" drops to the next line. If you create a similar sequence in Microsoft Word, however, the tab character drops onto the second line when the line gets too small. That is, in HTML the tab is 'stuck' to the word "text", but in Microsoft Word it is 'stuck' to the word "some".

I've tried to replicate this in HTML with various combinations of white-space, word-wrap, `<wbr>`, etc., but without success. Using emsp or a series of nbsp appears to be output at different sizes to a literal \t character.

**In HTML/CSS, is there any way to have the implicit line break in the same place, but get the tab to appear on the start of the second line instead?**

*Desired Output:*

```
Some text
\tsome 
more text
```

Comment: html handles tab symbol the same way as spaces, so you cannot make it work the way you want (basically tab is replaced with space), for the workaround - I'm not very sure how text should be displayed in different situations (first line/second line), when do you want to see indentation?